# Android progress bar not showing up in custom view

Tags: android, button, view

I'm trying to create a custom view that contains a button and a progressbar. This is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_button_primary"
        android:padding="@dimen/size_s"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size_m" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/white"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
        android:padding="@dimen/size_xxs"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And I created a custom view with

```
public class ProgressButton extends FrameLayout {

    private boolean isLoading = false;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Button button;
    String text;

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable OnClickListener l) {
        super.setOnClickListener(l);
        button.setOnClickListener(l);
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        this.text = text;
        button.setText(text);
    }

    public boolean isLoading() {
        return isLoading;
    }

    public void setLoading(boolean loading) {
        isLoading = loading;
        if (isLoading) {
            button.setText("");
            button.setClickable(false);
            progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        } else {
            progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
            button.setText(text);
            button.setClickable(true);
        }
        System.out.println("Progressbutton: IsLoading "+isLoading);
    }

    public ProgressButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    public ProgressButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    public ProgressButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        System.out.println("initview");
        View inflated = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.loader_button_primary, this);
        progressBar = inflated.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        button = inflated.findViewById(R.id.button);

    }

}
```

and use it like this

```
  val bt_sign_in = findViewById(R.id.bt_startup_sign_in) as ProgressButton
        bt_sign_in.setText("Log in")
        bt_sign_in.setOnClickListener{
            bt_sign_in.setLoading(!bt_sign_in.isLoading)
        }
```

And now something very weird happens:
- The text is appearing and dissapearing as how I expect.
- The progressbar is never showing up
- but when I set `android:visibility="visible"` in the XML file, I do see the progressbar as I expect. But after clicking it stays invisible.

Why does it stay hidden programmatically?

Comment: found it: I should've added `android:translationZ="2dp"` to the progressbar to have it float over the button.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have two clicklistener and with your logic

bt_sign_in.setLoading(!bt_sign_in.isLoading)

your toggle the progressbar and text.

2. Is VISIBLE and GONE imported correctly? From View Package?

Comment: Yes its from the correct package as it extends Framelayout which is a view, so preceding it isnt necessary.

Comment: Then it without super.setOnClickListener(l);